# Basic Google Apps Script Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a function using Google Apps Script where when I run the automation in my Google Sheet it then creates an event (or multiple events) on a shared Google Calendar.

I am new to coding and trying to complete this per a client request so would love any help/feedback!

I've watched a few videos and have referenced a few docs.

Here is the current state of my coding:

```
function createcalendarevent() {
  let communityCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_189f99fba6aef7d890a31b1bc2781f510052cab494ff152db93cf6cb7cb0d2e1@group.calendar.google.com");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['D4', 'B2:C3']);
    sheet.setActiveRangeList(rangeList);

};
```

Attaching a screengrab of the sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## *SUGGESTION*

You may use this `CalendarApp` service method called [createEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options) in your script with [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues). Also, based on your sheet data, you have some rows that don't have any Start time & End time yet, which needs to be [filtered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before creating the events, reducing any error in the process. You could try this tweaked script below:

```
function createcalendarevent() {
  let communityCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(`c_189f99fba6aef7d890a31b1bc2781f510052cab494ff152db93cf6cb7cb0d2e1@group.calendar.google.com`);
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  let rawData = sheet.getRange(`A1:C`).getDisplayValues().filter(x => x.join().length > 2);
  /** Iterate through each rows in your sheet Columns A, B, C
   * but only process rows with valid time values (rows with Start Time & End Time)
   * & create an event for each valid data */
  rawData.forEach( y => new Date(y[1]) != `Invalid Date` && new Date(y[2]) != `Invalid Date` ? createEvent(y[0],y[1],y[2],communityCalendar) : null )
};

function createEvent(eventName,startDate,endDate,communityCalendar) {
  // Creates an event
  var event = communityCalendar.createEvent(eventName,
    new Date(startDate),
    new Date(endDate));
  Logger.log(`Created "${eventName}" with Event ID: ${event.getId()}`);
}
```

### Demo

*Log Result:*

> [image]

*Sample events created:*

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: @Megan Verholy I hope this answer helps. If ever this answers your question, you may want to click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other beginners in using Google Calendar Service & Apps Script in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. That way, they'll be easily recommended to your post on their searches without the need of posting a duplicate question.